# Bluetooth concurrent LE Set Scan Enable and LE Create Connection Commands

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have found the some BLE device will allow you to do concurrent "LE Set Scan Enable" and "LE Create Connection" commands, and others (mainly CSR) will not.  Other than trying it on each device, is there a way to tell if device will allow this capability (i.e something like "LE Read Local Supported Features" command)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

See the LE Read Supported States command in the Bluetooth specification.

Please note that some Intel chips report that they support concurrent scanning/connection but actually fail to create a connection when you have a scan running. See https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble/issues/165. I also tried to report it here: https://communities.intel.com/thread/104509.

Comment: d'oh!  I don't know how I messed that.   Thanks.